# Verify mocked object is created in Python unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to test a function that optionally takes in a multiprocessing pool like object. If one is provided, then that pool will be used, if one is not it will create a ThreadPool to use.

I'd like to test this behavior. Specifically, that ThreadPool is called when appropriate, and that it isn't otherwise.

In the minimal example below, I'm trying to verify the call status of ThreadPool creation. I use a MockThreadPool because there are some downstream things I need to verify in a test environment that can only be checked in serial operation.

Currently this fails in TempTest.test_pool_created. How can I verify that `ThreadPool` is called?

Other than the example below, I've tried to mock `__init__` of `ThreadPool` without any luck.

temp.py

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def run(execution_pool=None):

    values = [1, 2]

    if execution_pool:
        out = execution_pool.map(lambda x: x+1, values)
    else:
        with ThreadPool(2) as p:
            out = p.map(lambda x: x+1, values)

    return out


if __name__ == "__main__":
    out = run()
    print(out)
```

temp_test.py

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock

from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

from temp import run

# Mock ThreadPool for diverting parallel code to serial
class MockThreadPool:
    def map(self, run_simulation, all_inputs, chunksize=1):
        map(run_simulation, all_inputs)


class TempTest(unittest.TestCase):


    def test_check_runs(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)


    # Want to test:
    # - ThreadPool is created when no execution pool is passed to run()
    # - ThreadPool is not created when an execution pool is passed to run()

    @mock.patch('multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool', return_value=MockThreadPool())
    def test_pool_created(self, fcn_pool):
        out = run(None)
        self.assertTrue(fcn_pool.called)

    @mock.patch('multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool', return_value=MockThreadPool())
    def test_pool_not_created(self, fcn_pool):
        out = run(execution_pool=MockThreadPool())
        self.assertFalse(fcn_pool.called)
```

Comment: What's the stack trace when it "fails"?

Comment: E      ` AssertionError: False is not true` `temp_test.py:24: AssertionError`

Comment: what do you want to test? You are trying to test glue code without any logic in this example. In any case, you can try this 
`from unittest.mock import patch 
@patch.object(ThreadPool, '__init__', return_value=None) fcn_pool.assert_called()`

Comment: @Rendrum  I tried that before posting here. I get the error:
`AttributeError: 'ThreadPool' object has no attribute '_worker_handler'` when I do.

Comment: In the actual code (not the example) there's lots of logic about when a pool should be created or not, and what kind of pool should be created. I'd like to test each of the reasonable sets of conditions and verify that the correct kind of pool is created.

Comment: I'm playing with this test and it, works...`@patch.object(ThreadPool, '__init__', return_value=None)
    def test_pool_not_created(self, fcn_pool):
        run(None)
        fcn_pool.assert_called()`

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before. You're patching `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`, but your code in the `temp` module is calling `ThreadPool` directly. I'm pretty sure it will work if you change your `patch()` call to this:

```
@mock.patch('temp.ThreadPool', return_value=MockThreadPool())
```